# Writing a Rust struct type that contains a string and can be used in a constant

Tags: rust

I'm getting started with Rust. I want to have a struct that contains (among other things) a string:

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Foo {
    string_field: &str,  // won't compile, but suppose String or Box<str> or &'a str or &'static str...
}
```

And I want to be able to declare `const`ants or `static`s of it:

```
static FOO1: Foo = Foo {
    string_field: "",
};
```

And I *also* want to be able to have it contain a string constructed at runtime:

```
let foo2 = Foo {
  string_field: ("a".to_owned() + "b").as_str(),
};
```

I could add a lifetime parameter to `Foo` so that I can declare that the string reference has the same lifetime. That's fine, except that it then seems to require an explicit lifetime parameter for *everything that contains* a `Foo`, which means that it complicates the rest of my program (even parts that don't care about being able to use constant expressions).

I could write

```
enum StringOfAdequateLifetime {
    Static(&'static str),
    Dynamic(Box<str>),  // or String, if you like
}
struct Foo {
    string_field: StringOfAdequateLifetime,
}
```

and that seems to work so far but clutters up writing out literal `Foo`s.

It seems obvious enough that the desired *runtime* behavior is sound: when you drop a `Foo`, drop the string it contains — and if it's static it's never dropped, so no extra information is needed to handle the two cases. **Is there a clean way to ask Rust for just that?**

(It seems like what I could use is some kind of "smart pointer" type to hold the string *that can also be written as a constant expression for the static case,* but I haven't seen one in the standard library, and when I tried to genericize `StringOfAdequateLifetime` to apply to any type, I ran into further complications with implementing and using the various standard traits like `Deref`, which I suspect were due to something about the differences between `Sized` and non-`Sized` types.)

Comment: Note that `const` in Rust is not what you might think. Constant value is literally substituted in place of constant, as if you've copied and pasted it everywhere. Static values, on the other hand, are real single values referenced from multiple places. The answer, however, applies to `static` values too.

Comment: @Cerberus I'm aware of the distinction. To clarify, I've changed the occurrences of "constant" to "constant expression" and changed the code sample to be a `static` item since it's plausible that `static` is what you want if you're doing things like storing constant strings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rust standard library has a built-in type for this exact use case, [Cow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html). It's an enum that can represent either a reference or an owned value, and will clone the value if necessary to allow mutable access. In your particular use case, you could define the struct like so:

```
struct Foo {
    string_field: Cow<'static, str>
}
```

Then you could instantiate it in one of two ways, depending on whether you want a borrowed constant string or an owned runtime-constructed value:

```
const BORROWED: Foo = Foo { string_field: Cow::Borrowed("some constant") };
let owned = Foo { string_field: Cow::Owned(String::from("owned string")) };
```

To simplify this syntax, you can define your own constructor functions for the type using a `const` fn to allow using the borrowed constructor in a constant context:

```
impl Foo {
    pub const fn new_const(value: &'static str) -> Self {
        Self { string_field: Cow::borrowed(value) }
    }

    pub fn new_runtime(value: String) -> Self {
        Self { string_field: Cow::Owned(value) }
    }
}
```

This allows you to use a simpler syntax for initializing the values:

```
const BORROWED: Foo = Foo::new_const("some constant");
let owned = Foo::new_runtime(String::from("owned string"));
```

Comment: This works! Thanks for also mentioning the possibilities of `const fn` — when I researched the errors I saw from trying to write various hopefully constant expressions, it wasn't at all clear that `const fn` was _currently available_, rather than only being a future feature.

Comment: Yeah, const fns are very useful, but they're currently only stabilized for a small subset of functionality - you can't do anything with control flow, for example.

Comment: Note that `new_runtime` can also take `impl Into<String>`, so that the caller doesn't have to call `String::from`. Or even `impl Into<Cow<'static, str>>`, so that string literals aren't cloned unless necessary.