# Create owned value on demand

Tags: rust

There is an existing value `a`, and I want to get a reference to either `a` or a new value `b` created on demand, depending on some condition. The code below won't compile. I would like to know what is the idiomatic way of doing so in Rust.

```
fn main() {
    let condition = false;

    let a: String = "a".to_string();
    let r: &String = if condition {
        &a
    } else {
        let b: String = "b".to_string();
        &b
    };
}
```

New example (in response to [@PitaJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74320059/20312298)):

```
struct S(i32);

fn main() {
    let condition = false;

    let a: S = S(0);
    let r: &S = if condition {
        &a
    } else {
        let b: S = S(1);
        &b
    };
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing a Rust struct type that contains a string and can be used in a constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63201351/writing-a-rust-struct-type-that-contains-a-string-and-can-be-used-in-a-constant)

Comment: @internet_user What is the exact code of using `Cow` for this specific use case? There is no `struct` in this example. And I don't see why this example needs a clone.

Comment: The string `b` is dropped at the end of the scope. There's no good way to produce a reference like that on demand. You should just change `r` to be a `String` instead of an `&String`.

Comment: @PitaJ Yes I know why it doesn't compile, but I cannot find an idiomatic way of letting it compile. Changing `r` to `String` would involve a move or clone of `a` which is not acceptable.

Comment: What's wrong with a move of `a`? Are you using it later on?

Comment: @PitaJ Yes `a` could be used later (not shown in the example).

Comment: @TSK as PitaJ said, the second example is just wrong because you are trying to create a borrow that outlives what it points to. This issue seems unrelated to the rest of the question, so I suggest you try to fix your second example, so that the *real* problem can be tackled.

Comment: @BlackBeans The question already says the example won't compile. The example only shows what I am trying to do. If I know a clean way of doing so then that would become the answer.

Comment: @TSK it's not about whether there is a clean way of doing, it's about whether there is a way *at all*. Currently, I suspect it isn't clear in your head who should own what in your code. Until that has been fixed, there is nothing more we can add besides the current answer; and we can't help you unless you provide more information about what you are trying to do (as said, the current example is *just broken*, there is no way to fix it that doesn't change it's meaning).

Comment: @BlackBeans There is obviously a way: Declare `b` outside the if-else block. It's just not as elegant or idiomatic as from my expectation.

Comment: @TSK There are tons of ways to change your program and make it compile, but there are none that *preserve its meaning* (for instance, you could simply remove all the code, and it would compile, but I suspect it's not what you intended, right?). My point is: we can't tell you which one is the right because we don't know what is the context of this code. Also, the current "meaning" is somehow ill-defined because you are trying to return a pointer, free the memory it points to, and use it later, which is why I said the example is broken: there is no way to preserve this "meaning".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249332/discussion-between-blackbeans-and-tsk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to use [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) in your case:

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;

let condition = false;

let a: String = "a".to_string();
let r: Cow<str> = if condition {
    Cow::from(&a)
} else {
    let b: String = "b".to_string();
    Cow::from(b)
};
```

For your second example, you have to add `Clone`. For an arbitrary clone type, you also have to instantiate the variants directly.

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct S(i32);

let condition = false;

let a: S = S(0);
let r: Cow<S> = if condition {
    Cow::Borrowed(&a)
} else {
    let b: S = S(1);
    Cow::Owned(b)
};
```

And this does mean that you can use `Cow<String>` in the same way.

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;

let condition = false;

let a: String = "a".to_string();
let r: Cow<String> = if condition {
    Cow::Borrowed(&a)
} else {
    let b: String = "b".to_string();
    Cow::Owned(b)
};
```

It's better to use `Cow<str>` for the same reason that it's better to use `&str` instead of `&String`: `&str` has a smaller representation in memory (one fewer pointer-sized field), and has all of the same capabilities.

Comment: I am wondering why changing `Cow<str>` into `Cow<String>` would fail this. I wrote a new example to show this problem. `Cow` doesn't seem to work on the new example.

Comment: The type parameter into `Cow` is the borrowed type, not the owned type. If you look at how it's implemented, as an enum, you'll see that one variant is `&B` and the other is `<B as ToOwned>::Owned`.

Comment: What if the owned type doesn't have a borrowed type (like `S` is the new example)?

Comment: @TSK added a couple more examples based on your follow-up

Comment: I am still feeling strange why I have to implement `Clone` while no clone shall happen in my examples.

Comment: `Cow` requires `ToOwned`. The easiest way to get `ToOwned` is by implementing `Clone`, since there's a [blanket implementation of `ToOwned` for anything that's `Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html#impl-ToOwned-for-Cow%3C%27a%2C%20B%3E). There's no `derive` for `ToOwned`, as far as I know, but you maybe could instead implement `ToOwned` manually.

Comment: I am talking about semantics. I think it should be clear from the question that the problem is caused by scoping but not cloning, etc. In fact it'd be a mistake if a clone happens. `Cow` works here because the reference is immutable. However if mutable reference is wanted, then `Cow` would clone the borrowed value. This diverges from the expected semantics where the mutation shall happen on the borrowed value itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249333/discussion-between-tsk-and-pitaj).

Answer (score 0):

The code is somewhat equivalent to the C++ code below:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    auto condition = false;
    std::string a("a");
    const std::string* ptr;
    if (condition) {
        ptr = &a;
    } else {
        std::string b("b");
        ptr = &b;
    }
}
```

If you are familiar with C++ you will see that `ptr` has the address of `b`, which is freed after code execution exits `else {...}` block. So `ptr` is pointing to an invalid memory address.

C++ compiler won't complain. This code will pass the C++ compiler. However code like this will have runtime problems. It's a good thing that Rust compiler catches such error at compile time, and force you to make sure that the lifetime of a copy of `b` is stored in `r`.